# WooCommerce - Auto generating API keys using our Application Authentication Endpoint give 401 Invalid URL error

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm attempting to use the REST API provided by WooCommerce to generate the Customer Secret and Customer Key values so that it could be used to invoke other WooCommerce REST APIs. I referred the documentation about generating the key values and managed to get it working using a mock endpoint in Postman used for the call_back URL in the API as mentioned in the document.

I created a POST service in my backend server and managed to setup a SSL certificate in the local environment with a domain mapped in hosts file in /etc directory. I ran the backend service and invoked the callback url through Postman and it worked. Then I used that as the call_back URL in the actual WooCommerce Auth endpoint to programatically generate the keys and save it in my DB. But I'm getting

"Access Denied" - Error: A valid URL was not provided..

When I checked the browser through devtools -> network noticed that there is a 401 Unauthorize error.

Here is the sample GET URL that is uesd for WooCommerce API key generation

```
http://localhost/woocommerce/wc-auth/v1/authorize?app_name=<SOME_NAME>&scope=read_write&user_id=36&return_url=http://localhost/woocommerce/&callback_url=https://foo.bar.dev:44329/api/services/app/woo_commerce_auth/6/callback

callback_url = https://foo.bar.dev:44329/api/services/app/woo_commerce_auth/6/callback
```

When the callback_url is a mock url generated using Postman it works fine

```
callback_url = https://513ca6ab-db16-4635-8d0b-9159e3b1e187.mock.pstmn.io/api/services/app/woo_commerce_auth/6/callback
```

Any clue why this happens, I could not find a way to troubleshoot this issue. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi I used a tool called "ngrok" to generate a simple proxy which creates an http and https endpoint to our application which then could be used for our testing. This eliminates the issue that I had earlier. And the necessary key data is forwarded to callback_url as expected. 

Seems like WooCommerce does not encourage having port number in the URL.

Now I'm getting an error saying "Error: An error occurred in the request and at the time were unable to send the consumer data." Any idea or clue on why this occurs.

Comment: Hi posting this for future reference.

Things to keep in mind when setting the callback_url,
1) Non HTTPS URL endpoint are not allowed.
2) URL should not be a localhost url (e.g https://localhost/callback would give an invalid URL error)
3) URL should not contain port number (e.g https://localhost:4320/callback or https://foo.bar.dev:4892/callback are invalid).
4) Callback URL should be a POST url.

The error in the previous comment came up because of an internal error in the callback_url backend service code (a 500 server error, not a WooCommerce issue)

Answer (score 2):

Hi posting this for future reference, and hope it would help others who face this problem as well.

Things to keep in mind when setting the callback_url,

1. Non HTTPS URL endpoint are not allowed.
2. URL should not be a localhost url (e.g localhost/callback would give an invalid URL error)
3. URL should not contain port number (e.g localhost:4320/callback or foo.bar.dev:4892/callback are invalid)
4. Callback URL should be a POST url

If an error such as `Error: An error occurred in the request and at the time were unable to send the consumer data.` is given after checking all the above check the backend service code related to the callback_url (I had a 500 server error which triggered this, it was not a WooCommerce issue)

Also a tool such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs) would be really helpful to setup an HTTPS endpoint in your local environment to test this.